# how are cold cranking amps calculated?

Tags: battery

As per the header, how are cold cranking amps calculated?
Im trying to understand what a rating of 20AH means if I want to use it as a starter source.

Comment: As the answers show ; AH and cold crank capacity are 2 different ways to define a battery.

Answer (score 2):

Cold Cranking Amp is a measure the ability of a fully charged new battery, in a cold environment (0°F/-18°C),  to discharge a load (in amperes) for 30 seconds, while still maintaining a voltage equal to or higher than 1.20 volts per cell.

It sounds like you are describing a deep cycle battery. Don't confuse a deep cycle battery with a starting battery. They are quite different. A deep cycle battery, rated in AH, usually cannot deliver the burst of energy needed for starting an engine.

source
[Deep Cycle vs. Starting Battery](https://www.batterysystems.net/deep-cycle-vs-starting-battery/)

Answer (score 0):

That 20AH will not tell you about the cranking capacity - you need to find the cranking capacity for the battery you are looking at - this is given by the manufacturer usually at a specific temperature.

The 20AH means the amount of current the battery can deliver : basically 20A for 1 hour (=20AH), 2A for 10 hours, or 1A for 20 hours. However, this is more a guide and not exact.